# "Display driver stopped working” during hi-def video playback

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card

When ever I play a high resolution (720hz) movie my destop PC shows a black screen and after a while shows message

> ialmrnt 5 display driver stopped working

I have the following configuration

- 1GB RAM DDR1
- windows xp OS processor- Intel Pentium 4 Processor Srm-Motherboard
- Graphics Driver Product Detected -Intel® 845G
- Current Driver Installed-6.14.10.3889
- Intel Chipset Software Installation Utility (Chipset INF) - Current Version Installed 9.1.0.1012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried updating your video driver to the latest version?

> http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/graphics/intel845g
>
> The latest Windows XP driver is version 14.10.3 dated 10/16/2007
>
> http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=9034&ProdId=865&lang=eng

That is usually a great starting point for any video related errors.